# Roblox: ServerScriptService.DamagableManager:48: attempt to index local 'mouse' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, roblox

Im trying to get player's mouse position. But im getting ServerScriptService.DamagableManager:48: attempt to index local 'mouse' (a nil value) error.

LocalScript that im trying to connect to Server Script:

```
local function onMousedClicked(actionName,inputState, inputObject)
    if inputState == Enum.UserInputState.Begin then 
        CheckIfDamagable:InvokeServer()
        print("MouseClicked")
    end
end
```

Server Script that im tring to get mouse info:

```
function CheckIfDamagableObject(player) 
     local mouse = player:GetMouse()

     --Unrelated codes here
end

CheckIfDamagable.OnServerInvoke = CheckIfDamagableObject
```

Answer (score 1):

As you discovered, when you pass the mouse object to the server, it becomes nil. According to the docs on [Player:GetMouse()](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Player/GetMouse) :

> This item must be used in a LocalScript to work as expected online.

You should just get the mouse position on the client and pass the result to the server using your RemoteFunction.

**LocalScript**

```
-- get the mouse object
local mouse = game.Players.LocalPlayer:GetMouse()

local function onMousedClicked(actionName,inputState, inputObject)
    if inputState == Enum.UserInputState.Begin then
        -- pass the mouse position and any other information to the server
        local result = CheckIfDamagable:InvokeServer(mouse.Hit)
        print("Mouse Clicked : ", result)
    end
end
```

**Script**

```
function CheckIfDamagableObject(player, mousePos)
    print("Mouse CFrame : ", mousePos)

    -- Unrelated codes here
end

CheckIfDamagable.OnServerInvoke = CheckIfDamagableObject
```

Comment: I was actually trying to take mouse position on serverside for preventing hack, But looks like its my only option Thank you so much!